# Is it possible to delay a validation until after a series of updates have been performed in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

One of my models has a `position` column and I have a draggable UI that allows users to change the model's position by dragging it to a new position. Updating the position will update the position of many other entries in that table.

I would like to be able to update all the affected models at once in a transaction, and then have the validation run that all positions are still unique, and roll back the transaction if the validation does not pass. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you want to use active record transactions block to wrap what you want to do with all your update!, if anything failed during all your record update because of the validation, it will rollback everything inside the active record transactions block.

Here is a link for you to read more http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

Also, if you really need to skip validation you can do

`@model.save(validate: false)`

and check again after you save everything like

`@model.valid?`

And you will need to manually throw an exception in the active record transaction block to cause everything to be rolled back